# How to add two spaces after split?

Tags: text, split, jinja2

On my code:

```
params: 
  "- key: fruits|value: apples, - key: travel_by|value: truck "

{% for elements in params.split(",") %}
{% for line in elements.split("|") %}
{{ line }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have this undesired result:

```
- key: fruits

value: apples



- key: travel_by

value: truck
```

Because I search the method to add 2 spaces "  " before "value:..." after the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

I added 2 spaces after "|" on the data structure.

```
params: 
  "- key: fruits|  value: apples, - key: travel_by|value: truck "
```

With this, the second split cut the phrase with the "|" synbol in two parts and the second part start with 2 spaces for the correct identation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add spaces like this

```
{{ "  " + line }}
```

OR

```
{{ "\t" + line }}
```

As per the documentation:

> - Adds two objects together. Usually the objects are numbers but if both are strings or lists you can concatenate them this way.

Comment: This add 2 spaces on two splited lines.